# Transfer ownership of Google Doc Add-on to another account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have been developing an Add-on for Google Docs using the script editor inside of Google Docs. The time has come for my team to submit the application to the store. We usually submit from one main account so that all of our Google-related apps come from the same place.

I shared the document that I've been working with, with this account. However when we try to "Deploy as Docs add-on" from that account we get an error that it is not the owner of that script.

I tried transferring ownership of the actual Google Doc to that user but it did not help.

How can I transfer ownership of the script so that his account can submit it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to transfer ownership of a script that is bound to a document.  You can add an owner to the developers console project, but when I tried that it didn't help.

I would recommend in the future creating your apps as standalone apps script files, it makes it much easier to keep track of your app and manage permissions.

For the right now, I would say your best bet is going in to the script as the user you want to own it, open the file menu and select Make a Copy.  This will create a copy of the script under their ownership.  The downside is that you may need to reconfigure any advanced Google services you are using. If you aren't using any advanced api's it might even be worth to copy and paste the code into a standalone apps script file.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the quick reply. I'll look into those options.